# If I was or If I were? Which one is grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, differences, subjunctive-mood

1. If I wasn't single and I had a girlfriend.
2. If I weren't single and I had a girlfriend.

Could you explain the difference?

Answer (score 0):

*If I wasn't /weren't single and I had a girlfriend*

Both are fine. "Was" is a tense form used here as a 'modal preterite', but this "were" is a mood form called 'irrealis'.

The difference is one of style level: "were" is here somewhat more formal than "was".

The irrealis mood form is unique to "be", and limited to the 1st and 3rd person singular. It's an untidy relic from an earlier system and some speakers usually, if not always, use preterite "was" instead.

Comment: Which one? Could you tell me?